# Using a seperate Views folder for mobile devices for an existing web site built in CodeIgniter using the the same Controllers and Models

Tags: codeigniter, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to use the same Models and Controllers which I have for our website,and then create two separate 'Views' folders in the application directory,one for web version and one for mobile version.And then load the desktop view if the website is being accessed from a desktop and mobile views in the other case.Kindly guide me if it can be done and how.

EDIT:
this is the function which assigns the View folder path in Codeigniter/system/loader.php:

```
function __construct() { 
$this->_ci_view_path = APPPATH.'views/'; 
$this->_ci_ob_level = ob_get_level(); 
$this->_ci_library_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH); 
$this->_ci_helper_paths = array(APPPATH, BASEPATH); 
$this->_ci_model_paths =     array(APPPATH); 
log_message('debug', "Loader Class Initialized"); 
}
```

so if I apply this check here:

```
if($this->agent->mobile()){ 
$this->_ci_view_path = APPPATH.'views/mobile_view';
}
```

Is this the way to go? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/wiki/Mobile_Detect) might help you to identify the type of device on which your web application is being accessed. Create a library for the same and include it in constructor of your controller's class.

Now you can change the view in a following way:

```
if ($detect->isMobile()) {
         $view_folder = 'views/mobile/';
}
else{
         $view_folder = 'views/normal/';
}
$this->load->view($view_folder.index, $data); //$data is the same variable that you are going to use into your views.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick rep, does this mean $this->load->view('example') would point to different files depending on the device(mobile or other)? means I would not have to change any code I am already using for loading views?

Comment: Exactly. You just have to make the similar layout for mobile and desktop devices. All functionality will remain the same.

Comment: how can I solve this error?         
Fatal error: Call to a member function library() on a non-object in /var/sandbox/ahsen/xferAdmin/system/core/Loader.php on line 63        Message: Undefined property: Users::$load

Filename: core/Loader.php

Comment: This link might helpful for you. http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/203790/ or http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/250592-codeigniter-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-library-on-a-non-object/

Comment: This worked for me, I could not load any library in Loader.php so I just included the Mobile_Detect file in the constructor function where the view folder path is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use userAgent provided by Codigniter http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/user_agent.html

EDITED Loader.php
Create custom view function like below one

```
public function my_view($view, $vars = array(), $return = FALSE)
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library('user_agent');
    if ($CI->agent->is_mobile())
    {
        // mobile view code goes here
        //return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
    }
    else
    {
        // browser code goes here
        //return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_object_to_array($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly see my first post,I edited it after visiting the link you provided.

Comment: you can create your  custom view function in Loader.php where you can check is mobile or not so will apply to whole app

Comment: yes I did that, but it is giving me the following error:     Undefined property: CI_Loader::$agent; even though I have loaded the user_agent library in autoload. where should I include this : $this->load->library('user_agent');

Comment: use $CI =& get_instance() and load with CI object and try

Comment: sorry I could not understand this :use $CI =& get_instance() and load with CI object..

Comment: $CI =& get_instance() ;$CI->load->library('user_agent');

Comment: now its giving this error:      A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Login::$load

Filename: core/Loader.php

Line Number: 56

Fatal error: Call to a member function library() on a non-object in /var/sandbox/ahsen/xferAdmin/system/core/Loader.php on line 56